# Cout and Cerr not synchronized

Tags: c++, cout

I have a problem with an output in c++.
I have a function A that calls another function B. In the function B in case of errors, I print an error message with `cerr`. In the function A, after the call of B, I print some lines with `cout`.

My problem is that randomly the error message is printed between the lines printed with `cout` even if the function B prints the error just before returning control to function A, so it should print the error message and only after this, it should return control to function A and print with `cout`.

I'm using CLion and its console.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Cout and Cerr are different stream, why should the are synchron?

Comment: If your cout and cerr are directed to same output window, may be it more obvious to use cout in both A and B?

Comment: I'm using cerr since it's an error message

Comment: Can you put the code here?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a single thread you probably just need to flush the streams before switching between them. You can either use `std::endl` which writes a new line then flushes or just call `std::cout.flush()` to explicitly flush stdout (and `std::cerr.flush()` to flush stderr).

Comment: Yes, this is one of the few situations where `std::endl` is appropriate.

Comment: Either cout and cerr have an endl at the end of the stream, and I tried to flush the cout and cerr after printing the error message but it still prints randomly

Comment: Are you using multiple threads? If not then this is probably an issue in CLion's console implementation.

Comment: No I'm not using threads, I'll try to compile it without CLion to check the output in the linux terminal

Comment: @giuseppe-dandrea: You don't need to compile it without CLion. You can compile with CLion and start it from terminal.

Comment: In the terminal the output is correct, so apparently it's a CLion problem

Answer (score 2):

As it's been already mentioned in one of the comments, `std::cout` and `std::cerr` are separate streams. Nowhere is it specified whether thy should be synchronized and how the should be synchronized. The console window merges these two streams just for the purpose of displaying them in one place but it doesn't try to divide the content of the streams into lines (and intermingle full lines) or anything like that.

Comment: Yes, I know that they shouldn't be synchronized, but is there a way to make the B function return only after complete the cerr output?